# How to initialize reducers? Reducer returns undefined

Tags: redux, react-redux, jsx, reducers

I'm totally new with Redux and reducers. I can't make my first code work. Can anybody tell me why (index.js) refer to BooksReducer? I have no such a prop, component, or file. And it throws me an error like this:
"Uncaught Error: Reducer "books" returned undefined during initialization. If the state passed to the reducer is undefined, you must explicitly return the initial state." How can I initialize it?

reducer_book.js:

```jsx
export default  function(){
    return
    [
      {title: 'Crash bandicoot'},
      {title: 'Crash bandicoot 2: Cortex strikes back'},
      {title: 'Crash bandicoot 3: Warped'},
      {title: 'Crash Team Racing'},
      {title: 'Crash Bash'}
    ]
}
```

index.js:

```jsx
   const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   books: BooksReducer
   });

    export default rootReducer;
```

App.js:

```jsx
 export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <BookList />
       </div>
     );
   }
  }
```

book_list.js:

```jsx
   class BookList extends Component{

     renderList(){
       return this.props.books.map((book) => {
           return( 
            <li key={book.title} className="list-group-item">{book.title}</li>
        );
      });
     }


   render(){
      return(
        <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
         {this.renderList()}
        </ul>
        )
    }
   }

    function mapStateToProps(state){
      return {
        books: state.books
    };
   }

   export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookList);
```

Comment: You need to import your reducer into index.js or just use the reducer function inline.

Comment: I imported it :/ import BooksReducer from './reducer_books'; But still don't get why it refers to BooksReducer when I don't have a component like that in my reducer_books file.

Comment: BooksReducer is your "default" export from that file. Its the equvilient of var BooksReducer = require("./books_reducer");
You can name it whatever your want.

Comment: You can read about ES6 modules at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Or soo, thank you! :)

Comment: Can you post the code where you set up your store?

Answer (score 2):

It *looks* like you've got a newline after your `return` statement in the reducer, so that's probably going to result in Javascript interpreting it as just `return;`, rather than `return [    ];`.  Try moving the open bracket for the array up to the same line as the `return` keyword.

Comment: Interesting remark, you have good eyes :) Now I have an other error: " Uncaught ReferenceError: renderList is not defined at BookList.render"

Comment: I especially logged-in SO just to upvote. Thanks alot @mark